# Blob media streams

Tags: blob, mediastreamsource

I am testing the following code example to create a Blob video URL that fetches the media file from an array and turns this into a blob to protect the video from being downloaded.

I have tried using MediaStreams but run into the trap of the video not being found or a blank page that cannot play the video, all videos are in the MP4 format.

[image]

Response

[image]

[image]

Screen Output

[image]